# Dpkg got deleted

Tags: ubuntu

By mistake dpkg pakage got deleted. So now if I try to install anything I get following error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ouch**. Okay, you should be still be able to fetch a copy of everything like this ...

```
# apt-get install --reinstall -d dpkg
# ls /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_*.deb
# cd /tmp
# mkdir deb
# cd deb
# ar x /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_*.deb
# tar xvzf data.tar.gz
# ls -l usr/bin
```

That nice long chain probably all has to be run as root.
If you've only lost the one file "/usr/bin/dpkg" you can copy it back into where it should be from "usr/bin/dpkg". It *should* be safe to extract the archive on top of the root directory, but I think it'd be best to reinstall dpkg properly after it's (sort of) working again.

```
# apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```